# Is there any solution to the timeout error in the connection of mysql with node in aws?

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-ec2

I am new to deploying in general and I am trying to deploy my back-end node project in aws. the mysql database is successfully deployed and works locally, meanwhile when I try to start the project in production it gives me a timeout error.

```
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at Connection._handleTimeoutError (/home/ubuntu/gmd-server/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:178:17)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  errorno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  fatal: true
}
```

I tried to extend the connection time in the node project but nothing changed.

My connection string:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'XXXX',
    user: 'XXXX',
    password: 'XXXX',
    database: 'XXXX',
});
```

How can I fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you check the aws page how to connect to a mysql instance?

Comment: @nbk yes i did check it

Comment: sorry wrong thread, there i said that you can check the name of the instanmce an then put it into your connection string

Comment: done those things @nbk

Comment: and a connection from  workbench works too ? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToInstance.html because you cann only access the instance without ssl, when  you are still in aws

Comment: as I said above the database connection works just fine when I run the project locally and also in workbench works fine @nbk

Comment: could you please add to your question a sanitized connetion string.

Comment: done. you can check it @nbk

Comment: i see only that      ,
  port     : process.env.RDS_PORT is missing, else i am sorry.

Comment: const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000; this is my port @nbk

Comment: thas has to be in the connection string else it takes the default 3306

Comment: for the db I am using the default port. the one I posted in the comments is the port of the back end @nbk

Comment: what do you have to loose, it is teh host or the port. and host have you checked

Comment: in workbench and while running it locally works fine with the default port. nevermind @nbk thanks for the help